# Samba Share + Gradle = Java IO Exception

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, samba, osx-server

I am using a new Mac OS X Server (OS X 10.11) with OpenDirectory and a samba share for remote homes setup.
Using Android Studio in this setup lead me to some issues with gradle. Gradle tries to lock files in the cache directory, which throws a java IOException. I could concentrate the problem to this demo code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;

public class FileLockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile file = null;
        FileLock fileLock = null;
        try
        {
            file = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "rw");
            FileChannel fileChannel = file.getChannel();

            fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();
            if (fileLock != null){
                System.out.println("File is locked");
            }
        } finally{
            if (fileLock != null){
                fileLock.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling and running this with the filename as the first argument shows the issue: A local file could be locked (whatever this means) but a file on a samba share throws this **exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Operation not supported
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1114)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
    at FileLockTest.main(FileLockTest.java:15)
```

**Now to my question**: Is there any way to enable the file lock feature for a samba share with mac OS X server? Am I missing some tricky setup with the samba server?

This really makes using Android Studio (/gradle) impossible with an OpenDirectory setup..

Comment: AFP shares lead to the same problem (under OS X 10.10.5). I believe in the OS X JRE quite a few file locking mechanisms have not been implemented. See https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2005/May/msg00544.html

Comment: Actually, it may not be the JRE  that does not implement locking. According to http://www.briandwells.com/main/Blog/Entries/2006/10/5_Subversion,_Mac_OS_X,_and_SMB.html it's OS X that does not support locking via `fcntl`.

Comment: Filed bug [JDK-8167023](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167023).